# how can we calculate the mean of every block in matlab?

Tags: matlab, mean

How can I divide an image into non overlapping blocks using indexing technique?

I want to calculate the mean of every block and display them individually.

I am using matlab R2012a.

indexing technique means: image(row1:row2,col1:col2);

i have different blocks in my image that is discrete blocks... i've calculated the individual mean... now the problem is

how to compare the mean of one block with the other block...

i want to track those block which have the same mean....

Comment: what have you tried? what do you mean by "indexing technique"? what do you mean by "display them individually"?

Comment: Are you, by any chance, referring to [mean-shift tracking](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~ismaila/MUSCLE/MSTracker.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html)?
For example, computing `mean` of non-overlapping 10x10 patches:

```
m = blockproc( img, [10 10], @(x) mean(x.data(:)) );
```

Comment: You need to use `mean(x.data(:))` because x is a block struct.